# jQuery Validate Not Working

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have an issue with my code it seems the `.validate` is not working but all the documents are connected and working sweet:

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <title>Site Name Quote Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://domain.co.nz/_assets/css/style.css"/>
<body>
    <div id="wrapperQuote">
        <h1>Site Name Quote</h1>

            <p class="quoteError"><?php echo validation_errors(); ?></p>

            <p class="step">Step 1: Company Details</p>

        <form id="quote" action="home/hosting" method="post">
            <fieldset>
            <legend>Company Details:</legend>
            <label for="companyName">Company Name: </label><input type="input" name="companyName" id="companyName"/>
            <label for="companySlogan">Company Slogan: </label><input type="input" name="companySlogan" id="companySlogan"/>
            <label for="companyContact">Company Contact: </label><input type="input" name="companyContact" id="companyContact"/>
            <label for="companyEmail">Company E-Mail: </label><input type="email" name="companyEmail" id="companyEmail"/>
            <label for="companyWebsite">Company Website: </label><input type="url" name="companyWebsite" id="companyWebsite" placeholder="http://"/>
            <label for="companyPhone">Company Phone: </label><input type="phone" name="companyPhone" id="companyPhone"/>
            <label for="companyFax">Company Fax: </label><input type="phone" name="companyFax" id="companyFax"/>
            <label for="companyAddress">Company Address: </label><textarea name="companyAddress" id="companyAddress"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" class="nextButton" value="Next" />
            </fieldset>
        </form>
        </div>
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="http://domain.co.nz/_assets/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
            <script src="http://domain.co.nz/_assets/js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
            <script src="http://domain.co.nz/_assets/js/quote.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**quote.js:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    //Home Validation
    $("#quote").validate({
        rules:{
            companyName:{
                required: true,
                url: true
            }
        }
    });
etc etc
```

Comment: are you gettin any error message?

Comment: have you tried setting the class to "required" on an input element and see if that works? That's another way to declare rules. And as above, are you getting any console errors?

Comment: What does _"does not work"_ mean?

Comment: Your code is working exactly as expected... http://jsfiddle.net/ex44R/1/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code, as you've posted it, is working as expected...  [jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ex44R/1/)

Regarding your code...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    //Home Validation
    $("#quote").validate({
        rules:{
            companyName:{
                required: true,
                url: true
            }
        }
    });
});
```

If you've put jQuery into [noConflict mode](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/), then [your code in noConflict mode is broken](http://jsfiddle.net/ex44R/2/).

When using `noConflict` mode, you must pass the `$` symbol into the `document.ready` function.  [Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ex44R/4/)...

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#quote").validate({
        // rules
    });
});
```

OR, you'd use `jQuery` in place of `$` everywhere.  [Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ex44R/3/)...

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    jQuery("#quote").validate({
        // rules
    });
});
```

Otherwise, without using no-conflict mode, it would just look like this.  [Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ex44R/5/)...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#quote").validate({
        // rules
    });
});
```